# How to use nslookup passing the dns through a variable?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

Friends, I am trying the implement a init container which will check if MYSQL is ready for connections and I am trying to use nslookup for this. The point is, how to pass the dns through a variable?

It worked like this:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup mysql-primary.default.svc.cluster.local; 
do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;']
```

But not like this:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup $(MYSQL_HOST); do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;']
```

Any Idea how I could get the second option working?

Comment: You can use variable from command line, from file etc. The question is, how do You want to pass this variable.

Comment: Sorry. didn't notice that you are using kubernetes. In Kubernets you can use ConfigMaps
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Answer (score 2):

`MYSQL_HOST` seems to be an environment variable and not a command.

`$(MYSQL_HOST)` will execute `MYSQL_HOST` as a command in a subshell (and that will not work in this case).

You probably want to use `"${MYSQL_HOST}"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `$()` executes a subshell and tries to evaluate a commend in there. What you actually want is variable expansion via `${}`.

Here a working example for you:

A pod with an init-container, with a `MYSQL_HOST` environment variable:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busybox-container
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
    - name: mysql-check
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'until nslookup ${MYSQL_HOST}; do echo waiting for mysql; sleep 2; done;']
      env:
        - name: MYSQL_HOST
          value: "mysql-primary.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

The pod starts after you create a corresponding service:

```
kubectl create svc clusterip mysql-primary --tcp=3306
```

For the sake of completeness: YAML of the service (not necessarily relevant in this case)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: mysql-primary
  name: mysql-primary
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3306"
    port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql-primary
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```